# Swift 5 How to get HTML from URL

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[Code Previously Done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd6Hg.jpg)

Hey Guys, I'm trying to get HTML data from a website, but not being able to and getting this error.
Can you please let me know what can I change and the data on the logs?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please don't post images, post text. And the *error* is actually a *warning*.

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should call `task.resume()` in the 41-th line of code.

Comment: Awesome, let me try that! Thank you :-)